# How do I create context of SimpleFragmentPageAdapter to getResources().getString()?

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-context

I have tried unsuccessfully to pass the context of SimpleFragmentPageAdapter via its constructor to the MainActivity, calling getResources().getString() on this context variable, in order to retrieve the titles for each tab in the page adapter.

Any help is much appreciated!

**SimpleFragmentPageAdapter.java**

```
public class SimpleFragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    final int PAGE_COUNT = 5;
    private Context context;

    String tabOne = context.getResources().getString(R.string.kiez);
    String tabTwo = context.getResources().getString(R.string.history);
    String tabThree = context.getResources().getString(R.string.culture);
    String tabFour = context.getResources().getString(R.string.food);
    String tabFive = context.getResources().getString(R.string.green);

    private String[] tabNames = new String [] {tabOne, tabTwo, tabThree, tabFour, tabFive};

    public SimpleFragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set view to activity:main
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Find ViewPager for easy swiping
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        // Create adapater object to know which fragment should be shown based on user interaction
        SimpleFragmentPageAdapter pagerAdapter = new SimpleFragmentPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);

        // Set adapter to ViewPager
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        // Find TabLayout for tab identification
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);

        // Set ViewPager to TabLayout
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Relevant error log for reference:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: can you post activity_main.xml

Comment: done (see above for edited version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to access context that is not initialized yet.

**Make it like this**:

```
private Context context;

private int[] tabNames = new int[] {R.string.kiez, ....};

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
}

 @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
       context.getResources().getString(tabNames[position])
 }
```

**Or better:**

```
private Resources resources;

private int[] tabNames = new int[] {R.string.kiez, ....};

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Resources resources) {
    super(fm);
    this.resources= resources;
}

 @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
       resources.getString(tabNames[position])
 }
```

Comment: I tried the second solution and received the same error, NPE. To make sure, I made the following change to the constructor:  SimpleFragmentPageAdapter pagerAdapter = new SimpleFragmentPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getResources());

Comment: I also tried the first solution and received the same error. In fact, nothing is different in terms of programming logic from your answer and my original code: I had initialized the context variable. Hmm.

Answer (score 1):

`context` is `null` until `SimpleFragmentPageAdapter` is initialized, you need to move the variable's initialization inside the constructor:

```
public class SimpleFragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    final int PAGE_COUNT = 5;
    private Context context;

    String tabOne;
    String tabTwo;
    String tabThree;
    String tabFour;
    String tabFive;

    private String[] tabNames;

    public SimpleFragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;

        tabOne = context.getResources().getString(R.string.kiez);
        tabTwo = context.getResources().getString(R.string.history);
        tabThree = context.getResources().getString(R.string.culture);
        tabFour = context.getResources().getString(R.string.food);
        tabFive = context.getResources().getString(R.string.green);

        tabNames = new String [] {tabOne, tabTwo, tabThree, tabFour, tabFive};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution: your pageAdapter don't really need to hold the context by itself.

You want to access the string, and why not you create a global static context to do this job? Usually I will make one from my `Application` instance, thus I can use the context to get resource from every where I want.

Another advantage of this approach is, you can avoid memory leak. Those life cycle related component don't need to hold the context by themself, the context from `Application` is safe to use while the application is alive.